# How to access methods of subclass in object array C#?

Tags: c#

How can I set/get the value of an object in an object array?

Currently I get:
*"object does not contain a definition for 'value' and no extension method"*

Example C#;

```
    public class myObjClass
    {
        public int value = 5;
    }

    public class myObjClass2
    {
        public float[] pos = new float[2];
    }

    public void test()
    {
        myObjClass myObj = new myObjClass();
        myObjClass2 myObj2 = new myObjClass2();

        object[] objArr = new object[2];
        objArr[0] = myObj;
        objArr[1] = myObj2;
        Debug.Print(myObj.value.ToString());
        Debug.Print(objArr[0].value.ToString()); // how?

    }
```

Comment: **object** does not contain a definition for 'value', **myObjClass** does. You need to cast. Or make it an `myObjClass[] objArr`. Class names should start with an Uppercase, by the way.

Comment: why are you using object array?

Comment: Don't use object it is creating the issue.  Use a real class type.  Use following : myObjClass[] objArr = new myObjClass[2];

Comment: As far as the compiler knows, `objArr[0]` contains a plain `object`, not a `myObjClass`.

Comment: well I updated to code to make a bit more sense why I use object array, I have different classes i want to store in the array.

Comment: Then see the answer by EpicKip, in particular with the `is` and `as` operators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its because a generic `object` does not have the property `value` your class `myObjClass` has. To fix this you could **[cast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105(v=vs.80).aspx)** the item to your class like so:

```
((myObjClass)objArr[0]).value.ToString()
```

*Only do this ^ if you are sure of the type*

---

**Instead you could also check it first:**

With **[as](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt(v=vs.71).aspx)**:

```
var item = objArr[0] as myObjClass;
if( item != null ) // Item will be null if its not a 'myObjClass'
{
    //Do stuff with item
}
```

Or with **[is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is)**:

```
if( objArr[0] is myObjClass )
{
    var item = (myObjClass)objArr[0];
    //Do stuff with item
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When using an object array you have to cast to the real type (here: myObjClass) before accessing the fields:

You can access the object like this

```
((myObjClass)objArr[0]).value
```

but I would not recommend. Can´t you have your array to be the concrete type

```
var array = new myObjClass[42]
```

A compact safe alternative to retrieve the value is

```
(objArr[0] as myObjClass)?.value
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast object to known type which is `myObjClass`, like:

```
((myObjClass)objArr[0]).value.ToString();
```

Or you can use `reflection`

```
var valueString = objArr[0].GetType().GetProperty("value").GetValue(objArr[0]);
Debug.Print(valueString.ToString());
```

Hope helps,

Answer (score 1):

Technically you can put it as

```
  Debug.Print((objArr[0] as myObjClass)?.value.ToString());
```

We try casting `objArr[0]` as `myObjClass` and if succeed get `value` and turn it to `string`. If `objArr[0]` is not `myObjClass` we return `null` as a string

However, a *much better way* is to implement `ToString()` in both classes of interest:

```
public class myObjClass
{
    public int value = 5;

    public override string ToString() {
      // When debugging we want to know "value"
      return value.ToString();
    }
}

public class myObjClass2
{
    public float[] pos = new float[2];

    public override string ToString() {
      // When debugging we want to know "pos[0]" and "pos[1]" values
      return $"{pos[0]} : {pos[1]}";
    }
}
```

And then put an easy

```
// Just print out debug info (we don't want to know the actual objArr[0] class)
Debug.Print(objArr[0].ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a single object, that indeed is an instance of `myObjClass`, and has a `value` field, but you have two references to it.

One (`myObj`) is known to the compiler to be of type `myObjClass`, and it can guarantee that it has a `value` field.

The other (`objArr[0]`) is only known to the compiler to be of type `object`, and it cannot guarantee that it has a `value` field.

For example, you could do:

```
 objArr[0] = (random.Next() > 0.5) : myObj ? myObj2
```

where we're gonna decide at runtime, based on the value of a random number, which will be the type of the actual object at `objArr[0]`.

So, if this was allowed, half of the time `objArr[0].value` would be correct, and half of the time it will be an error.